# Floats that span the text width and the margin

Tags: floats, context, context-mkiv

What is the correct way of placing floats that span the text width and the
margin?

If the width of the float content is increased, ConTeXt does not reserve space
in the margin which leads to overlapping content. At the moment I adjust the
vertical placement manually using `\godown`, but that can't be the right way.

```
\startplacefigure [location=margin]
  \godown [7cm]
  \externalfigure [dummy] [width=\marginwidth]
\stopplacefigure
```

Here the example code.

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]

\setupfloat
  [figure]
  [location=inner]

\showframe
\starttext

\startplacefigure
  \externalfigure [dummy]
    [height=4cm,
     width=\dimexpr\textwidth+\rightmargintotal\relax]
\stopplacefigure

\startplacefigure [location=margin]
  \externalfigure [dummy] [width=\marginwidth]
\stopplacefigure

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: (untested) have you tried adding the `bleed` option to the big figure. See the details manual fod example.

Comment: Do you mean the `\bleed[…]{…}` command? AFAIK this reserves the same bounding box as the original figure but scales it or prints it at a different spot.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another work around: place an extra margin figure containing a rule of the height of the first figure.  Of coures you have to remember to not give the new figure a number.

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]

\setupfloat
  [figure]
  [location=inner]

\showframe
\starttext

\startplacefigure
  \externalfigure [example-image-a]
    [height=4cm,
     width=\dimexpr\textwidth+\rightmargintotal\relax]
\stopplacefigure

\startplacefigure [location=margin,number=none]
  \vrule height 4cm width 0pt
\stopplacefigure

\startplacefigure [location=margin]
  \externalfigure [example-image-b] [width=\marginwidth]
\stopplacefigure

\stoptext
```

[image: Sample output]