# text, margin, and text + margin width floats without using tufte class

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, tufte, sidenotes

I want to use the `marginfigure`, `figure*`, and `figure` environment as defined in `tufte-book` and `tufte-handout` classes (see respectively Figure 1, 2 and 3 in the [template example](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf)).

It means being able to use following environments:

- **`marginfigure`:** A figure in the margin that has `\marginparwidth` width, with its caption below in the margin;
- **`figure`:** A figure in the main text that has `\textwidth` with, with its caption besides in the margin (and bottom aligned);
- **`figure*`:** A figure over main text and margin that has `\textwidth +  \marginparsep + \marginparwidth` width, with caption below in the margin.

[image]

However, since most of my source-code is intended for `KOMAscript` classes, I don't want to switch to one of the `tufte` classes just because of that.

**Question:** How to emulate those environment outside `tufte` classes?

---

> ***This question have been solved by the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301910/64454)***, i.e., using the `sidenotes`-package. However, for keeping someone else from following tortuous paths/culs-de-sac I took, I let herein below my attempts to solve my issue. It gather the previous versions of my question together.
>
> Contents:
>
> 1. Related packages and TeX.SE questions,
> 2. Successful workaround for `marginfigure` using `capt-of` package,
> 3. Trying to emulate environments out of `tufte` classes source-code:
>
>    - Successful (but unwieldy) for `marginfigure`;
>    - Unsuccessful for `figure` and `figure*`

### 1. Related packages and TeX.SE questions

I am aware of the [`floatrow`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2561/64454) package, but even if it seems great for `figure` and `figure*`, I couldn't find how to handle `marginfigure`.

I also found [Implementing marginfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115139/implementing-marginfigure) that solves the problem in an other way.

- *`figure` and `figure*`:* I then looked around in TeX.SE as I was blocked, and found several related threads:

  - [Floats that span the text width and the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83197/floats-that-span-the-text-width-and-the-margin): Don't handle caption in the margin
  - [Using \MarginFigure command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135286/using-marginfigure-command):
  - [How to make sure the images properly float on the marginpar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63167/how-to-make-sure-the-images-properly-float-on-the-marginpar): on the good way.
  - I finally found [Margin Figures/Captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/margin-figures-captions) that suggest to use `tufte` classes.

### 2. Successful workaround for `marginfigure` using `capt-of` package

I achieved a workaround for `marginfigure` using `capt-of` package, as described [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=3660).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
    Some text.
    \marginpar{%
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image}%
        \captionof{figure}{My caption}%
    }%
    More text.

    Another paragraph
\end{document}
```

It's great, but doesn't solve the issue for `figure` and `figure*`

### 3. Trying to emulate environments out of `tufte` classes source-code

I've read through the sources, and since it all has been implemented (+ managing floats, etc.), my idea was so to re-implement the commands of `tufte-common.def` available in [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex) to reproduces those environment.

I am thus trying to adapt macros and environments defined in [`tufte-common.def`](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def) in order to let them standalone.

I succeeded for `marginfigure`, but compilation fails when I redefine `figure` and `figure*`.

- `marginfigure`: I succeeded in copying `tufte-book` classe's `marginfigure` environment.

See MWE below.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{placeins}

    \usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry} % tufte-handout definitions

\makeatletter
        \input{my-tufte-marginfigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Say what?!

    \begin{marginfigure}%
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{My caption}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

where `my-tufte-marginfigure` is following excerpt of [`tufte-common.def`](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def)

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\@tufte@marginfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\newcommand*{\@tufte@caption@font}{\@tufte@marginfont}
\newcommand*{\@tufte@caption@justification}{\justifying} %% or \RaggedLeft or \RaggedRight 

% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\newcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
    \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
    \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.5pc}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}

\newsavebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}

\newenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
{\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
        \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
            \@tufte@caption@font% %%some font definition%%
            \def\@captype{#2}%
            \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
            \@tufte@caption@justification%
            \@tufte@margin@par%
            \noindent%
        }
        {\end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
}


%%
% Margin figure environment

\newenvironment{marginfigure}[1][-1.2ex]%
    {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{figure}}%
    {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}

%%
% Margin table environment

\newenvironment{margintable}[1][-1.2ex]%
{\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{table}}
    {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}
```

- `figure` and `figure*`: I tried to do the same for `figure` and `figure*`.

However, the compilation fails.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}

\makeatletter
        %\input{my-tufte-marginfigure} %% cf. hereinabove
        \input{my-tufte-figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My long caption is not \emph{that} long!}
        \setfloatalignment{b}
    \end{figure}

%   \begin{figure*}[h]
%       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
%       \caption{Some caption!}%
%   \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Where `my-tufte-figure` is following excerpt of [`tufte-common.def`](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def). (I know it's very long, but I'm sure it's pretty close to the minimal form!)

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{optparams}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{changepage}

%%
% `symmetric' option -- puts marginpar space to the outside edge of the page
%   Note: this option forces the twoside option (see the .cls files)
\newboolean{@tufte@symmetric}
%%\DeclareOptionX[tufte]<common>{symmetric}{
    \setboolean{@tufte@symmetric}{true}
    %%%\@tufte@info@noline{The `symmetric' option implies `twoside'}
    %%%\ExecuteOptionsX[tufte]<common>{twoside}
%%}

%DEBUT
%%
% A collection of macros to be used with the new Tufte-style float environments.
% \setfloatalignment forces the caption placement to be treated as top, bottom, etc.
% \forcerectofloat forces the float to be treated as if it were appearing on a recto page.
% \forceversofloat does the same, but for verso pages.

\newcommand{\@tufte@float@debug@info}{}% contains debug info generated as the float is processed
\newcommand{\@tufte@float@debug}[1]{% adds debug info to the queue for output
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@float@debug@info}{}}%
    {\def\@tufte@float@debug@info{#1}}%
    {\g@addto@macro\@tufte@float@debug@info{\MessageBreak#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\floatalignment}{x}% holds the current float alignment (t, b, h, p)
\newcommand{\setfloatalignment}[1]{\global\def\floatalignment{#1}\@tufte@float@debug{Forcing position: [#1]}}% manually sets the float alignment
\newboolean{@tufte@float@recto}
\newcommand{\forcerectofloat}{\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{true}\@tufte@float@debug{Forcing page: [recto]}}
\newcommand{\forceversofloat}{\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{false}\@tufte@float@debug{Forcing page: [verso]}}

% Boxes to temporarily store our float and caption
\newsavebox{\@tufte@figure@box}
\newsavebox{\@tufte@caption@box}

    %MANDATORY
% Save original LaTeX float environment
\let\@tufte@orig@float\@float
\let\@tufte@orig@endfloat\end@float
    %MANDATORY/
% New length for tweaking float captions
\newlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}
\setlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{0pt}

% Store the caption and label contents
\newcommand{\@tufte@stored@shortcaption}{}
\newcommand{\@tufte@stored@caption}{}
\newcommand{\@tufte@stored@label}{}

\long\def\@tufte@caption[#1][#2]#3{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{#3}}%
    {\gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{#1}}%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{-#2}% we want a positive offset to lower captions
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@caption{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\@tufte@label}[1]{%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\@tufte@fps}{}

\newboolean{@tufte@float@star}
\newlength{\@tufte@float@contents@width}
%FIN

%%
% Compute lengths used for full-width displays

\newlength{\@tufte@overhang}% used by the fullwidth environment and the running heads
\newlength{\@tufte@fullwidth}
\newlength{\@tufte@caption@fill}

\newcommand{\TufteRecalculate}{%
    \setlength{\@tufte@overhang}{\marginparwidth}
    \addtolength{\@tufte@overhang}{\marginparsep}

    \setlength{\@tufte@fullwidth}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\@tufte@fullwidth}{\marginparsep}
    \addtolength{\@tufte@fullwidth}{\marginparwidth}

    \setlength{\@tufte@caption@fill}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\@tufte@caption@fill}{\marginparsep}
}

\AtBeginDocument{\TufteRecalculate}

%%
% Globally sets a boolean

\newcommand*{\gsetboolean}[2]%
    {% based on code from ifthen pkg
        \lowercase{\def\@tempa{#2}}%
        \@ifundefined{@tempswa\@tempa}%
        {\PackageError{ifthen}{You can only set a boolean to `true' or `false'}\@ehc}%
        {\@ifundefined{#1\@tempa}%
            {\PackageError{ifthen}{Boolean #1 undefined}\@ehc}%
            {\global\csname#1\@tempa\endcsname}%
        }%
    }

%%
% Detect if the subfigure package has been loaded

\newboolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}
\setboolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}{false}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{subfigure}
    {\gsetboolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}{true}}
    {\gsetboolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}{false}}%
}

% Write our own aliases for the \checkoddpage and \ifoddpage or \ifcpoddpage commands
\newboolean{@tufte@odd@page}
\setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{true}
\newcommand*{\@tufte@checkoddpage}%
    {%
        \checkoddpage%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@changepage}}%
            {%
                \ifoddpage%
                    \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{true}%
                \else%
                    \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{false}%
                \fi%
            }{%
                \ifcpoddpage%
                    \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{true}%
                \else%
                    \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{false}%
                \fi%
            }%
    }


%%
% Define a float environment to place the captions in the margin space

\newenvironment{@tufte@float}[3][htbp]%
{% begin @tufte@float
    % Should this float be full-width or just text-width?
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{star}}%
        {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@star}{true}}%
        {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@star}{false}}%
    %   
    % Check page side (recto/verso) and store detected value -- can be overriden in environment contents
    \@tufte@checkoddpage%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@odd@page}}%
        {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{true}%%%\@tufte@float@debug{Detected page: [recto/odd]}
            }%
        {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{false}%%%\@tufte@float@debug{Detected page: [verso/even]}
            }%
    % If the float placement specifier is 'b' and only 'b', then bottom-align the mini-pages, otherwise top-align them.
    \renewcommand{\@tufte@fps}{#1}%
    %%%\@tufte@float@debug{Allowed positions: [#1]}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}\OR\equal{#1}{B}}%
        {\renewcommand{\floatalignment}{b}%%%\@tufte@float@debug{Presumed position: [bottom]}
            }%
        {\renewcommand{\floatalignment}{t}%%%\@tufte@float@debug{Presumed position: [top]}
            }%
    % Capture the contents of the \caption and \label commands to use later
    \global\let\@tufte@orig@caption\caption%
    \global\let\@tufte@orig@label\label%
    \renewcommand{\caption}{\optparams{\@tufte@caption}{[][0pt]}}%
        %QUESTION: is ##1 ok?
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\@tufte@label{##1}}% 
    % Handle subfigure package compatibility
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}}%
        {% don't move the label while inside a \subfigure or \subtable command
        \global\let\label\@tufte@orig@label%
        }{%
        }% subfigure package is not loaded
    \@tufte@orig@float{#2}[#1]%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
        {\setlength{\@tufte@float@contents@width}{\@tufte@fullwidth}}%
        {\setlength{\@tufte@float@contents@width}{\textwidth}}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@figure@box}%
        \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\@tufte@float@contents@width}\hbox{}%
}
{% end @tufte@float
            \par\hbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\ifthenelse{\prevdepth>0}{\vspace{-\prevdepth}}{}% align baselines of boxes
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % build the caption box
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}%
        \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\marginparwidth}\hbox{}%
            \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@caption}{}}%
                {\@tufte@orig@caption[\@tufte@stored@shortcaption]{\@tufte@stored@caption}}%
                {}%
            \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}%
                {\@tufte@orig@label{\@tufte@stored@label}}%
                {}%
            \par\vspace{-\prevdepth}%% TODO: DOUBLE-CHECK FOR SAFETY
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % now typeset the stored boxes
    \begin{fullwidth}%
        \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\linewidth}%
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
            {\@tufte@float@fullwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
            {\@tufte@float@textwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
    \@tufte@orig@endfloat% end original LaTeX float environment
    % output debug info
%   \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@debug}}%
%       {%
%           \typeout{^^J^^J----------- Tufte-LaTeX float information ----------}%
%           \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}%
%           {\typeout{Warning: Float unlabeled!}}%
%           {\typeout{Float label: [\@tufte@stored@label]}}%
%           \typeout{Page number: [\thepage]}%
%           \def\MessageBreak{^^J}%
%           \typeout{\@tufte@float@debug@info}%
%           \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}%
%           {\typeout{Symmetric: [true]}}%
%           {\typeout{Symmetric: [false]}}%
%           \typeout{----------------------------------------------------^^J^^J}%
%       }{%
%       }%
    % reset commands and temp boxes and captions
    %%\gdef\@tufte@float@debug@info{}%
    \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
    \let\label\@tufte@orig@label%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@figure@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@caption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@label{}%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{0pt}% reset caption offset
}

\newcommand{\@tufte@float@textwidth}[3][0pt]%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}\OR\boolean{@tufte@float@recto}}
            {% asymmetric or page is odd, so caption is on the right
                \hbox{%
                    \usebox{#2}%
                    \hspace{\marginparsep}%
                    \smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}%
                }%
                \@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [right]}%
            }{% symmetric pages and page is even, so caption is on the left
                \hbox{%
                    \smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}%
                    \hspace{\marginparsep}%
                    \usebox{#2}%
                }%
                \@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [left]}%
            }%
    }

\newcommand{\@tufte@float@fullwidth}[3][0pt]%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\floatalignment}{b}}%
            {% place caption above figure
                \ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}\OR\boolean{@tufte@float@recto}}%
                    {\hfill\smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}\par\usebox{#2}\@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [above right]}}% caption on the right
                    {\smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}\hfill\par\usebox{#2}\@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [above left]}}% caption on the left
            }{% place caption below figure
                \ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}\OR\boolean{@tufte@float@recto}}%
                    {\usebox{#2}\par\hfill\smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}\@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [below right]}}% caption on the right
                    {\usebox{#2}\par\smash{\raisebox{#1}{\usebox{#3}}}\hfill\@tufte@float@debug{Caption position: [below left]}}% caption on the left
            }%
    }

%%
% Redefine the figure environment to place the captions in the margin space

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][htbp]%
    {%
        \begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{figure}{}%
    }{%
        \end{@tufte@float}%
    }


%%
% Redefine the table environment to place the captions in the margin space

\renewenvironment{table}[1][htbp]%
    {%
        \begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{table}{}%
    }{%
        \end{@tufte@float}%
    }

%%
% Full-width figure

\renewenvironment{figure*}[1][htbp]%
    {%
        \begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{figure}{star}%
    }{%
        \end{@tufte@float}%
    }


%%
% Full-width table

\renewenvironment{table*}[1][htbp]%
    {%
        \begin{@tufte@float}[#1]{table}{star}%
    }{%
        \end{@tufte@float}%
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the `sidenotes`-package:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{sidenotes}
    \usepackage{kantlipsum}
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry} % tufte-handout definitions


\begin{document}
    \begin{marginfigure}%
        \caption{My caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{marginfigure}

    \kant[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \sidecaption{My caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure*}
        \sidecaption{My caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: *I knew it!* Someone *had* to have wanted similar to be! But I couldn't find the relevant package... Thank you for not having let me fiddle with tufte-classes any longer!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @DG'

Comment: I second these comments. I really wanted something like this, preferably with KOMA script, and the `tufte` class has been giving me nothing but grief.

Answer (score 5):

I am rather late to the party, but there might be another recent option worth checking out, namely the [`kaobook`](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) class. The style is a bit different, but it picks up many ideas from [`tufte`](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) and is under active development (as of 2021).