# Text and Figures

Tags: floats, formatting, margins

I try to create a financial report with LaTeX and have trouble how to. It should look like the attached picture. I already created some documents with LaTeX, so I know basically how it works.

[image]

My first try had been the `marginnote` package. Thats somehow does it but the figures float out of the margin without any control.

I'd like minimal margins for the whole page, and have achieved this by the geometry package. It's important, that there is either a picture on the left side or free space and that e.g. Picture 1 stays with Text 1.

Is there any way to achieve this without an enormous effort?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look on this question: [text, margin, and text + margin width floats without using tufte class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301769/64454) - the solution uses the `sidenote` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `paracol` package is interesting for you. See this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{0.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
 \noindent
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[1-4]
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\newpage
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
 \noindent
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[5-8]
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good package. Is it possible to add vertical space between two image?

Comment: Yes, put something like `\\[2ex]` or `\\[1cm]` between the pictures.

Comment: Great. On a first glace it looks perfectly what I've searched for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sidenotes`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes) package as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301910/64454).

Your pictures are not top aligned, but remains on the same page than surrounding text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{sidenotes}
    \usepackage{kantlipsum}
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm]{geometry} % tufte-handout definitions
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
    \begin{marginfigure}%
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{marginfigure}
    \kant[2-3]
    \begin{marginfigure}%
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{marginfigure}
    \kant[4]
    \begin{marginfigure}%
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-c}
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and your solution. I will test it.