# Tufte margin caption effect with floatrow

Tags: tufte, floatrow

Is it possible to acquire a caption in the margin of the next paragraph (as in the example below), but using floatrow instead of the entire tufte class?

[image]

This is the standard beside caption from floatrow, for comparison:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you convert it to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sidecaption` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry} % tufte-handout definitions


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \sidecaption{My caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301769/text-margin-and-text-margin-width-floats-without-using-tufte-class/301910#301910).

However, be aware that in many cases you will have to tweak margin sizes to obtain a decent balance in the page.