# Side notes adjust options. Can I "liberate" all the margin for sidenotes?

Tags: floats, xetex, margins, geometry, marginpar

I have to deal with a lot of sidesnotes, so, I would like to "liberate" all margin for this, Here the code, as you see, sidenotes go after the page:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{book}

    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

    \usepackage{sidenotes}


    \begin{document}



    Lorem ipsum\sidenote{Here} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus id odio quis maximus.\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} Suspendisse aliquet ante dui, sit amet feugiat magna molestie vitae. Quisque\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} pretium mollis\sidenote{Here} erat, sit amet iaculis ante volutpat ac. Proin id euismod lectus. Fusce finibus ipsum non purus volutpat, id luctus tortor congue. Duis finibus\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} arcu\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} rutrum, tempus dolor\sidenote{Here} non, tincidunt lacus. Morbi consequa\sidenote{Here}t erat\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} ac nisi viverra rhoncus. Aliquam at varius\sidenote{Here} justo.\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
    \end{marginfigure} Sed in commodo enim. Aliquam tincidunt velit eu pulvinar dignissim. Sed vitae\sidenote{Here} pretium nulla.

    Pellentesque\sidenote{Here} sollicitudin nunc at eros suscipit porttitor. In hendrerit \sidenote{Here}tempor arcu. Cras ut tellus\sidenote{Here} tincidunt metus ullamcorper venenatis. Donec at augue diam. Ut nec magna congue,\sidenote{Here} blandit libero vitae, tincidunt sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent eu congue\sidenote{Here} dui. Aliquam vel magna ut enim cursus viverra eget non libero. Sed lacinia lectus\sidenote{Here} ut lacus tempus, vitae mollis nisl venenatis. In eu \sidenote{Here}magna id tellus tristique porttito\sidenote{Here}r. Aliquam non semper ipsum. Vestibulum velit turpis, pharetra in urna ut, pretium loborti\sidenote{Here}s nunc. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam sed dolor dictum, tempor purus quis, consequat massa\sidenote{Here}.



    \end{document}
```

To solve this problem, I would like to write sidenotes in all margin: Here a picture :[image]

Obs: Any answer are welcome, even using other document class, like Koma-Script, Memoir, etc. I am using book, but I can easily move to another :)

**EDIT:** To make things more clear:

Look at this other example: 
[image]

The sidenotes/figures/table etc begins **after** the Chapter, section title etc, I want to place the side notes in the **whole** margin, independent of what is in the body text. 
So, the **desired result** is this one:

[image]

With header:

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the sidenotes to float. As I see it, using sidenotes for images is like using footnotes for floating figures: it doesn't help the reader and quickly becomes a mess. It just won't fit in. What about turning those sidenotes into sidefigures and referring to them in the text?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301910/9424

Comment: @Joseph, Sometimes I have a big image with some sidenotes (the notes are not caption, they are separated things, I just want a way to adjust all possible sidenotes in the hole magin, to get more space, unfortunately, this question does not solve my problem. As the showframe shows, the sidenotes notes go into the margin, top with the body text, I want the hole margin, no matter where is the body text.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `tufte-latex`, it's paying a lot attention to large margins with notes and pictures in the margins.

However, in my experience (around 2010) `tufte-latex` was too "fragile" for writing a longer (100+ pages) scientific text. It's a thing to make your text look *very* nice at a price of having to tune some things manually. (For example I had an idea of placing references into side margins, but never could cope with overfilling them.)

When you write a longer scientific text, like a PhD thesis, you actually want your layout to go away and not to bother. So, in the end I took `memoir` for my work. It has few subtile advantages to standard `book` (and similar) classes, `koma` would probably be comparable.

Now, `memoir` also has some extensive management of side notes, there you can distinguish between floating and non-floating side notes. However, in my experience, the LaTeX support for these things is still quite fragile. (But I'd love to be corrected.)

For example, side notes have several problems, mostly connected to page breaks:

- A side note might "grow" into a bottom margin, if used not wisely
- In a seldom, but reoccurring circumstances, a side note might "err" the oddness/evenness of the page it is on. Basically it happens when a paragraph starts on the one page, so is the code that decides what page the side note is on, but the actual side note (and the remaining part of the paragraph) are on the next page.
- Many "floating" side notes fill up the "buffer" for floating objects, so you run into various problems with too many floats quite fast.
- Non-floating side notes may overlap, when issued too close to each other.

Currently, I know no automatic solution that would allow one to use a lot of longer margin notes without thinking about their placement, "floatness", with "overfilling" the notes to the next page, etc. So, any serious document with many side notes is a layout hassle that cost a lot of time.

Comment: Yes! I am not able to find a nice solution for this, instead, I am searching a "better way", the problem is more related with the size of the notes, than to the quantities, (sometimes big texts or images), so I really need the hole margin for my text, unfortunately, I did not fount an way to do this, even in Koma or Memoir classes, I did not found a parameter that  allow me to "break" the margin tu use the entire paper size for placing sidenotes.

Comment: You might want to look into how `tufte-latex` implements its `fullwidth` environment. Also, the package `sidenotes` was mentioned above for better side notes.

Comment: Oh, you mean the margin both on the side and in the top margin? You might want to adjust the position of a normal margin note with a negative value, to "bump" it up there. But I'd say it's typographically a bad idea.

Comment: I updated the question, maybe make more sense now. I just to use the whole margin, without leave headers and etc. Sometimes we deal with big images and want to put them in the total paper size.

Comment: so you want to put an image at the margins, also in the header, in the footer, and above the chapter entry. As Oleg said, you can adjust the position of a sidenote using an offset value, but I agree that typographically it's a bad idea. I guess it's possible to "reserve" this whole space using some Koma-Script using `scrlayer-scrbase` + sidenotes, but testing this idea is beyond my humble knowledge. Anyway, if the images are too big, or if there are many images in a page, no matter how much page space you use, there will always be a lack of space.

Comment: Also, as a tangent note. What I did with very large images was to keep them full width (with as little margin as in main text, no side notes were used), but to mitigate large _captions_ to the next page. Just use a new `figure` environment, decrement the counter if needed and issue a `caption` immediately.